# How to display a math formula in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-view

My app is supposed to show some engineering formula.

How can I display a formula in my app?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: if it is just one formula, use an image

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no direct way to show math formula in android TextView, 
But you can use [MathJaxWebView](https://github.com/vinayakmestri/mathjaxWebView) and use the webview to show formula using it. Visit the link for more infomation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use MathJax also but it is slightly heavy. So I propose you to use jqMath.
(jqMath is a JavaScript module that makes it easy to put formatted mathematical expressions in web pages.)

*Download this JavaScript Library here. http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html 
There`s a link to download that Library from link called "download jqMath"

*For more Info visit: https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-display-math-formula-and-equation-in-android-application/

Good Luck!!